# Calculate number of days between two dates (without using modules)

Tags: perl, date

I searched around for this a lot, and it appears all solutions are making use of some module or the other.

I have 2 dates in *yyyymmdd* format. I'd like to know of a simple way to calculate the number of days between these dates, **without** using any modules.

Example:
Date 1: 20130625
Date 2: 20130705

Number of days = 10

PS: I cannot use any modules due to restrictions on the server I will be running the script on. Perl version - **5.8.4**

Comment: All the modules you would need for this does not need any compilation and can be used the same way you will upload your perl script. **That is without considering the version of perl installed which may already have most of the needed modules installed by default.**

Comment: I have edited my question with my perl version. Could you specify which module? Is this possible with Time::Local?

Comment: You're using an unsupported version of Perl that is over eight years old. You're also saying that you can't use CPAN - which is most of the power of Perl. I strongly suggest that you get yourself a reasonable working environment before trying to do any work :-)

Comment: The script is meant to be deployed on multiple live and extremely business-critical servers, which are pretty old and were configured by another team. Doing any sort of modifications, like adding perl libraries, means a HUGE administrative overhead of approvals - I just want to avoid all that and get the job done another way. I'm sure you can understand :-)

Comment: If you don't have [Time::Local](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::Local), you can always copy/paste its source into your script. You basically just need `_daygm`, which is only about 10 lines long.

Comment: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RJBS/Time-Piece-1.21/Piece.pm can be used without installing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sub yyyymmdd_to_rata_die {
    use integer;
    my ( $y, $m, $d ) = $_[0] =~ /\A([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\z/
        or return;

    my $adj;

    # make month in range 3..14 (treat Jan & Feb as months 13..14 of prev year)
    if ( $m <= 2 ) {
        $y -= ( $adj = ( 14 - $m ) / 12 );
        $m += 12 * $adj;
    }
    elsif ( $m > 14 ) {
        $y += ( $adj = ( $m - 3 ) / 12 );
        $m -= 12 * $adj;
    }

    # add: day of month, days of previous 0-11 month period that began w/March,
    # days of previous 0-399 year period that began w/March of a 400-multiple
    # year), days of any 400-year periods before that, and 306 days to adjust
    # from Mar 1, year 0-relative to Jan 1, year 1-relative (whew)

    $d += ( $m * 367 - 1094 ) / 12 + $y % 100 * 1461 / 4 + ( $y / 100 * 36524 + $y / 400 ) - 306;
}

print yyyymmdd_to_rata_die(20130705) - yyyymmdd_to_rata_die(20130625);
```

Comment: I was trolling for comments on code copying, but no one bit :(

Answer (score 6):

Expression returns 10.

```
(
    Time::Piece->strptime('20130705', '%Y%m%d')
  - Time::Piece->strptime('20130625', '%Y%m%d')
)->days
```

[Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aPiece) is part of the core Perl distribution [since v5.9.5](http://perlpunks.de/corelist/version?module=Time%3A%3APiece).

Comment: Should have mentioned this before, but my perl version is 5.8.4 , and it doesn't recognize this module :(

Comment: Why are you using an out of date and unsupported version of Perl?

Answer (score -1):

Its simple:

1) for each date:

1.1) turn years into ydays

1.2) turn months into mdays

1.3) make sum days + mdays + ydays

2) substract that two values